# wordpress multisite wp-admin redirects to login

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress mu

I have the following challenge on a Wordpress Multisite on IIS using IE.

When I attempt to access `wp-admin` at the sub site level I get redirected to the login, which never is displayed.

For example if I am on the sub site and add wp-admin to my address,my browser, ie 9, redirects me to:

```
wp-admin%2F&reauth=1, which does not display a login page.
```

Logging into the wp-admin at top site works fine, for example when I enter:
`main/wp-admin` I am redirected to `.../wp-logpin.php` and I can login IF I reload (F5) the page.

The plot thickens!  Once I have logged in to main site I can browse to `main/subsite` `/wp-admin` successfully.

Environment - ver. 3.4.2. on IIS

I am new to WordPress, MySQl, and PHP, but am favorably impressed by it all.  Any suggestions on course ware would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved - My major concern about being redirected to the main WP-Admin page was that bloggers in my multi site would be able to access other blogs dashboards since they were entering at the top, i.e.  bolgsite/wp-admin instead of blogsite/subsite/wp-admin.

This was an erroneous assumption based on having just created an admin user for the sub site and then logging in at the top level wp-admin.  WP only lets have access to the sub site dashboard.

Conclusion - If an Admin is created specifically for a sub site, the only dashboard visible will be for that sub site regardless of where the user access the wp-admin page.  Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Um, are you the same person who asked the original question, only using a new account?